# Memory leak about the window.rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have found a strange memory leak problem. In my `AppDelegate`, I set the

`self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;`

After setting the `rootViewController` point to `loginViewController`,and I finish the login logic.Then I go to my `homeViewController`, I call AppDelegate to change its rootViewController:

`[UIApplication shareApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController = homeViewController;`

However, I notice the `-(void)dealloc` in `loginViewController` is not called, i think a memory leak happen. After I search many similar question and test and test. I found that if I put the code in the same `queue`, memomy leak is disappear. For example,

```
NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:blockOperation];
NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      [UIApplication shareApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController = homeViewController;
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:blockOperation];
```

`loginViewController dealloc is successful` I really wonder why it is? 
and more `loginViewController` is `local variable`

Comment: "However, I notice the -(void)dealloc in loginViewController"...  you notice it doing *what*?

Comment: sorry. I have updated it. I mean `the dealloc` is not called

Comment: And you don't have any other references to it (instance variables)?

Comment: @Droppy I think no

Comment: did you happen to have a scenario like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41406823/1840269